# Destination Paste Debugging Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Admittedly I'm a rookie with this kind of stuff so it's probably a simple error :)

Purpose of the macro is to

Open a specific workbook, copy row 2, paste into row 2 of a different specific workbook, saveas new workbook and loop through the rows until column B is empty, saving each individual workbook copies separately and not changing the original.

This code seems simple enough but for some reason it keeps debugging when it gets to the destination line

```
Sub CopyDataAndSave()
       Dim reportWorkbook As Workbook
       Dim fundingWorkbook As Workbook
       Dim reportSheet As Worksheet
       Dim fundingSheet As Worksheet
       Dim copyRange As Range
       Dim saveName As String
       Dim lastRow As Long
       Dim i As Long
   
   ' Open the "Report" workbook
       Set reportWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Downloads\FundingTestingExtract.xlsx")
       Set reportSheet = reportWorkbook.Sheets("Report") 
   
   ' Open the "Funding Worksheet" workbook
       Set fundingWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Downloads\1st Wire Sheet (mapped     Purchase).xlsx")
       Set fundingSheet = fundingWorkbook.Sheets("Data") 
   
   ' Find the last row in column B of the "Report" sheet
       lastRow = reportSheet.Cells(reportSheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
   
   ' Loop through each row in column B
       For i = 2 To lastRow
   
       ' Define the range to copy
       Set copyRange = reportSheet.Range("A2:AI2").Offset(i - 2, 0)
       
       ' Paste the data into the "Funding Worksheet" starting from cell A2
      copyRange.Copy Destination:=fundingSheet.Range("A2:AI2")
       
       ' Define the save name
       saveName = reportSheet.Cells(i, "A").Value & reportSheet.Cells(i, "D").Value &     reportSheet.Cells(i, "B").Value & ".xlsx"
       
       ' Save copy
       fundingWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\Downloads\" & saveName
       
       ' Close the newly saved workbook without saving changes to the template
       fundingWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
       
       Next i
   ' Close the workbooks
       reportWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
       fundingWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
   ' Clean up
       Set reportWorkbook = Nothing
       Set fundingWorkbook = Nothing
       Set reportSheet = Nothing
       Set fundingSheet = Nothing
       Set copyRange = Nothing
    End Sub
```

Comment: Remove `fundingWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False` which is on top of `Next i`. It close the `fundingWorkbook` at the end of the first round loop (i=2). In the next loop (i=3), object `fundingWorkbook` is nothing. It raises error.